# position AdMob to bottom when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, admob

I have setup AdMob in my ViewController and it's positioned at the bottom. Everything is good until I hide my navigation bar. The AdMob frame goes up when my navigation bar is hidden. How can I make it stick to the bottom of my view? Here's what I have

```
    -(void)navBarTransition:(BOOL)hide
     {
       [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];

       //addjust frame height when ads is visible
       if(hide)
       {
       CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height + GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height);

       [bannerView_ setFrame:frame];
       }
     }
```

Comment: check your frame's y Coordinator

Comment: CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height - GbannerView.frame.size.height,GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height);

Comment: @ CocoaMatters Matters. I keep geting 0 as my Y point for bannerView_.
@ priyanka. I tried that before but it also didnt work. the bannerView still wont stick to the bottom.

Comment: When are you calling navBarTransition: in relation to adViewDidReceiveAd:? I was able to only reproduce the error when I called navBarTransition in my adViewDidReceiveAd: during the time an animation was happening

Answer (score 0):

Just before hiding the navigation bar, move the origin.y down by the height of it. Also ensure you have no autosizing masks (flexible top/bottom margins?) interfering with your positioning.

```
CGRect bFrame = bannerView_.frame;
CGFloat newY = bFrame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
bFrame.origin.y = newY;
[bannerView_ setFrame:bFrame];
```

If this doesn't work you could try using [CJPAdController](https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController) (*Disclosure: I wrote this class*). If you implement this class, you can simply adjust your code to the following (have just tested and it appeared to work as you would like it to):

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];
if(hide)
    [CJPAdController sharedManager] fixAdViewAfterRotation];
```